# run nestjs app with oracle on docker with colima in local docker error of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker, docker-compose, colima

docker-compose>>
`version: '3.9'

services:
app:
build:
context: .
target: development
dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
volumes:
- ./:/usr/src/app/
- /usr/src/app/node_modules/
container_name: app
environment:
DEBUG: '*'
SERVICE_DB: 'oracle'
ORACLE_HOST: oracle
ORACLE_PORT: 1521
ORACLE_DB: payroll
ORACLE_USER: payroll_user
ORACLE_PASSWORD: payroll_pass
NODE_ENV: development
REDIS_HOST: redis
REDIS_PORT: 6379
REDIS_PASSWORD: '0000'
REDIS_TTL: 180
REDIS_TLS: 'false'
QUEUE_NAME: 'dummy-queue'
QUEUE_ENDPOINT_URL: 'http://localstack:4566/000000000000/dummy-queue'
ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'dummy'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'dummy'
AWS_REGION: 'eu-central-1'
X_API_KEY: 'PYOLag4HmTwVNQCnFaCEwOoIQPC7e3C2'
AD_CLIENT_ID: 'de5bfce5-4448-4cf5-b5c3-6c32d83f57a7'
AD_TENANT_ID: '52f315ba-de63-468c-87c7-a8247c35c604'
AD_IDENTITY_METADATA: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
AD_ISSUER: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/v2.0'
command: npm run start:debug
restart: 'always'
ports:
- '3000:3000'
- '9229:9229'
depends_on:
oracle:
condition: service_healthy
redis:
condition: service_healthy

redis:
image: redis:6.0.5-alpine
command: redis-server --requirepass 0000
ports:
- 6379:6379
healthcheck:
test: ['CMD', 'redis-cli', '--raw', 'incr', 'ping']
timeout: 10s
interval: 10s
retries: 10

oracle:
image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:21.3.0-slim
platform: linux/x86_64
environment:
# User for ORACLE_PASSWORD is 'system'
ORACLE_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
ORACLE_DATABASE: payroll
TARGET_PDB: payroll
APP_USER: payroll_user
APP_USER_PASSWORD: payroll_pass
volumes:
- ./docker/oracle/custom-healthcheck.sh:/opt/oracle/custom-healthcheck.sh
- ./docker/oracle/custom-healthcheck.sql:/opt/oracle/custom-healthcheck.sql
- oracle_data:/opt/oracle/oradata
ports:
- '1521:1521'
healthcheck:
test: ['CMD', 'sh', 'custom-healthcheck.sh']
interval: 30s
timeout: 10s
retries: 10
start_period: 20s

volumes:
oracle_data:`

> > > > Dockerfile.dev <<<<<

```
FROM ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:21 AS development
ENV NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=7168'
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y wget curl tar gcc-c++ make && \
    curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - && \
    yum install -y nodejs && \
    yum clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/instantclient
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node ./.npmrc ./
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
```

colima
PROFILE    STATUS     ARCH      CPUS    MEMORY    DISK     RUNTIME    ADDRESS
default    Running    x86_64    2       8GiB      60GiB    docker

the error

```
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.dev                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 683B                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 169B                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:19                                                                                                        5.2s
 => [app 1/7] FROM ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:19@sha256:7b58303824cde221887787f05908f965be94d7fbf2bcf2d1cb1eed8c3bb5ab38                                                 23.3s
 => => resolve ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:19@sha256:7b58303824cde221887787f05908f965be94d7fbf2bcf2d1cb1eed8c3bb5ab38                                                      0.0s
 => => sha256:cb69e978226429300bcf6bc2718629ad9f0f1fcf82f7833a3406608ddf17c083 2.26kB / 2.26kB                                                                                           0.0s
 => => sha256:6c155ac704793dcb7073826df00d3a9b17b24771b1140817aeeab8067cb4a3bd 82.04MB / 82.04MB                                                                                        10.1s
 => => sha256:7b58303824cde221887787f05908f965be94d7fbf2bcf2d1cb1eed8c3bb5ab38 741B / 741B                                                                                               0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:6c155ac704793dcb7073826df00d3a9b17b24771b1140817aeeab8067cb4a3bd                                                                                               12.6s
 => [app internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                    0.4s
 => => transferring context: 306.10kB                                                                                                                                                    0.3s
 => [app 2/7] RUN yum update -y &&     yum install -y wget curl tar gcc-c++ make &&     curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - &&     yum install -y nodejs &&     y  356.4s
 => [app 3/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [app 4/7] COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => [app 5/7] COPY --chown=node:node ./.npmrc ./                                                                                                                                         0.1s
 => ERROR [app 6/7] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                      2.2s
------
 > [app 6/7] RUN npm install:
#0 1.965 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
#0 1.973   what():  std::bad_alloc
```

how can i fix it? i try many way increase colima spec but not working